# What is the difference between IoT and a Smart Environment?

Tags: definitions

I have read through a number of papers with a focus on either Smart Environments or IoT.

[Another paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c90/6adc35824d5d36029b31cb5bf3fb08eacbba.pdf) uses IoT and Smart Environments in the same context, almost interchangeably, which makes me believe they are one and the same, however this should not be the case as a Smart Environment (as discussed by [Cook and Das](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.9518&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) to consist of 4 components:

1. Decision
2. Information
3. Communication, and
4. Physical Layers (or components).

Not one paper I have come across address the what IoT is in the context of a Smart Environment and visa versa. Are they the same, is IoT a sub component of a Smart Environment, is it a trait, a characteristic?

*Some insight would be appreciated, ideally with references too.*

Comment: Related to https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-is-the-difference-between-iot-and-industry-4-0, but this question seems more abstract. Nobody owns the definition of IoT, people writing papers are allowed to be lazy.

Comment: Yup, this can't be answered. Although I would suggest that "smart environment" is a subset of IoT.

Comment: @Mawg Funny, I would have suggested the opposite based on the purpose of an IoT (framework) and what is defined as a Smart Environment. An IoT (framework) facilates the communication between agents, tranducers, etc in a network and ensures data can be transferred between these devices, while a Smart Environment: firstly on definition, attempts to collect data from devices on a network, process it by performing operations on the data, and 'output' the result to the environment to enhance the experience in that environment. Secondly, a Smart Environment (ref question) encapsulates all 4 aspects

Comment: @Mawg cont. while an IoT (framework) only considers the physical and communication layers and possibly information - but this does not conform to the strict 'definition' of a an IoT (framework), that is to facilitate ubiquitous computing and ensure comminucation between devices (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things including references used). _Please note, this is my understanding of it_

Comment: You have convinced me :-)

Comment: @Mawg I do not wish to make this a discussion, but I am in the process of writing a paper on Smart Environments, where I will most definitely make the distinction between what IoT is and what a Smart Environment is. I can notify you when it has been _published_. Hopefully it will at the very least, clear up uncertainty and confusion ;)

Comment: That would be great! Possibly a link from the question?